# Using jQuery.scrollTo in Foundation 4, multiple options not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, scrollto

I am using the latest version of Zurb Foundation 4 framework for a one-page site. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, Chrome browser for testing. I have menu items on the page (not a links, I'm using spans to contain them) which when clicked activate the scrollTo plugin. I have the jquery.easing.1.3 plug-in also enabled.

The problem is I need to use multiple options in the scrollTo commmand as follows:

```
$.scrollTo('#div_internet',1000,{offset: '-60', easing: 'easeInOutExpo'});
```

When I specify either option (offset or easing) by themselves in the brackets, this code works. When I put them both in there with a commma delimiter, the code breaks. I cannot find any suggestions or anyone else who has run into this problem. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For further references;

All options need to be entered between curly brackets and comma separated (including that duration).

```
$(item).scrollTo(itemPosition, {option1: int, option2: 'string', option3: {object1, object2}})
```

For example, the proper syntax for passing many offset to the [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin (assuming an #id position) along with with easing and duration is:

```
$.scrollTo(itemId, {offset: {top:-offY, left:-offX}, easing : 'easeInOutCubic', duration : 2000});
```